# Sudo-ed script seems to ignore sudo -u <user> line prefix

Tags: sudo

As far as I know, `sudo -u <user>` can be used in a script that is being run as sudo in order to “cancel out” the inherited sudo, hence run the line that follows as the regular user . Only it doesn’t seem to me to be working like this, at least not in the context below: it’s as if `sudo -u <user>` doesn’t do anything!

To illustrate this, take two trivial Bash scripts, a `master.sh` script, and a `slave.sh` script:

master.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo -u dad /home/dad/Downloads/slave.sh
```

slave.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! -v DOTNET_ROOT ]] # If variable is not set ...
then
  echo "DOTNET_ROOT needs to be set ..."
else
  echo "No need to set DOTNET_ROOT."
fi
```

Here’s what happens when running the different scenarios:

```
dad@DadsGram~/Downloads $ echo $DOTNET_ROOT
/home/dad/.dotnet
dad@DadsGram~/Downloads $ ./slave.sh 
No need to set DOTNET_ROOT.
dad@DadsGram~/Downloads $ sudo ./master.sh 
DOTNET_ROOT needs to be set ...
dad@DadsGram~/Downloads $ sudo ./slave.sh 
DOTNET_ROOT needs to be set ...
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

The second `sudo` is not "cancelling out" the previous `sudo`;
it's overriding it. 
Like putting a toupee on top of a hat, in contrast to taking off the hat.

I'm guessing that you understand
that `sudo` has the side-effect of stripping out environment variables. 
(Side note: since that is not the *primary* purpose of `sudo`,
it would be nice if you would explain more clearly what you understand
and what you're trying to accomplish.) 
The second `sudo` overrides the UID-setting done by the first one. 
It cannot revert the entire environment
to what it was before the first `sudo`;
it cannot magically restore environment variables that were removed.